# How to use ComponentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I got array with objects from API and then I use:

```
   componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getAllPosts()
        this.props.getAllComments()
    }
```

Then I put data to my Redux but when I want to change this array (for instance add new object), I need to refresh the page, because it doesn't work asynchronous...

So I solved to use `ComponentDidUpdate` but it renders every second hundreds times, What i need to do?

Comment: If there is change in state, the component re-renders itself, you need not explicitly use the componentDidUpdate. You use componentDidUpdate , only if you need to know component and its child components have updated or not .

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wrap the setState call in an if block, as the [docs describe here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)
Any call to setState inside of ComponentDidUpdate, will cause ComponentDidUpdate to be called again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare is there any difference between the old props(state) and the new(updated) props(state) or the code may exec in dead loop. Just like the following snippet:

```js
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, _prevState) {
    const { activeKey: prevActiveKey } = prevProps
    const { activeKey } = this.props
    if (prevActiveKey !== activeKey && !!activeKey) {
      this.getTemplateList()
    }
  }
```